# unexpected error message, arduino SharpIR

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to use a GPY2Y0A21Y IRsensor, but I am having trouble making the code work. I downloaded SharpIR but got a bug when using one of its functions,

```
#include <SharpIR.h>


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
SharpIR sharp("A1", 25, 93, 1080);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

and this is the error message

```
/var/folders/_z/t_qth0vd0xj6fxvyp_k5nvc00000gn/T/arduino_modified_sketch_475607/sketch_jan17a.ino: In function 'void setup()':
sketch_jan17a:7: error: no matching function for call to 'SharpIR::SharpIR(const char [3], int, int, int)'
 SharpIR sharp("A1", 25, 93, 1080);
                                 ^
/var/folders/_z/t_qth0vd0xj6fxvyp_k5nvc00000gn/T/arduino_modified_sketch_475607/sketch_jan17a.ino:7:33: note: candidates are:
In file included from /var/folders/_z/t_qth0vd0xj6fxvyp_k5nvc00000gn/T/arduino_modified_sketch_475607/sketch_jan17a.ino:1:0:
/Users/jeroenturkstra/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SharpIR/src/SharpIR.h:29:5: note: SharpIR::SharpIR(uint8_t, uint8_t)
     SharpIR(uint8_t _sensorType, uint8_t _sensorPin);
     ^
/Users/jeroenturkstra/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SharpIR/src/SharpIR.h:29:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 4 provided
/Users/jeroenturkstra/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SharpIR/src/SharpIR.h:25:7: note: constexpr SharpIR::SharpIR(const SharpIR&)
 class SharpIR
       ^
/Users/jeroenturkstra/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SharpIR/src/SharpIR.h:25:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
/Users/jeroenturkstra/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SharpIR/src/SharpIR.h:25:7: note: constexpr SharpIR::SharpIR(SharpIR&&)
/Users/jeroenturkstra/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SharpIR/src/SharpIR.h:25:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
exit status 1
no matching function for call to 'SharpIR::SharpIR(const char [3], int, int, int)'
```

I am not super familiar with libraries and such so I have no clue what is wrong with this code. All I got is that the function doesn't exist. I did download SharpIR btw. If anyone can help, it would be appreciated (had the example code from this site https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/SharpIR)

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be legit, looking at the [SharpIR declaration](https://github.com/guillaume-rico/SharpIR/blob/master/SharpIR.h#L29). Maybe the guide that you are following is deprecated and not compatible with your installed library?

```
class SharpIR
{
  public:

    SharpIR (int irPin, long sensorModel);
    int distance();

  private:

    void sort(int a[], int size);

    int _irPin;
    long _model;
};
```

The object initialization requires only a pin number and a long that identifies the sensor model. **BUT** looking at the error in your question it seems that the declarations is implemented with the sensor identification number as first argument and the pin number as second. I think you should really open up the source in your local installation and check it out. You can print it in terminal with:

```
cat /Users/jeroenturkstra/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SharpIR/src/SharpIR.h
```

(I cannot open Dropbox link right now...)